# How can we create database and table in Amazon Athena using CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena

Is there any way to create DataBase and Table in Amazon Athena using CloudFormation.
I referred to AWS documentation and there seems to be only one resource which can be created using CloudFormation.

Ref :

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-template-resource-type-ref.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-athena-namedquery.html

Comment: CloudFormation doesn't seem to support this right now. You can always use a [custom resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/walkthrough-custom-resources-lambda-lookup-amiids.html) to do it.

Comment: Take a look at this answer for a solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50419635/697243

Answer (score 6):

It is now possible to create Athena Table in CloudFormation through the Glue Data Catalog:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-glue-table.html

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21338759)

Comment: I was puzzled how Glue can create Athena tables, but it indeed works. Once created via `AWS::Glue::Table` it shows up in the Athena console.

Comment: The official documetation lacks examples. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279209/partitioning-athena-tables-from-glue-cloudformation-template) for a complete example.

Answer (score 0):

I think its possible with (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/AWS_Athena.html)
AWS::Athena::WorkGroup
&
AWS::Athena::NamedQuery

**NamesQuery - where you will provide your SQL/DDL to create the table.

Example from AWS

---

https://athena-in-action.workshop.aws/20-howtostart/201-self-paced/2013-cloudformation.html

Comment: I believe the `AWS::Athena::NamedQuery` CloudFormation resource will create a Saved query on the "Saved queries" tab.

Comment: Please include a working example of this. The linked workshop has a `CREATE TABLE` statement in the named query, but something else must be executing it and I can't figure out what it is.